# Partition file system changed to "RAW" after Windows 10 update

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-update

Windows on my workstation has been updated recently to a new build... In result of what I lost access to my 2nd partition.
In Windows Disk Manager it shows RAW in file system column of broken volume.
When I try to browse to the drive on file explorer it suggest that I should format this partition.

Ubuntu 16.04 also doesn't recognize the drive.

I heard about similar problems happening with early "Anniversary" updates.
However, I'm using Windows 10 Pro with deferred updates on, so I'm not sure if it is possible that it is still the same issue or just new bug?

I tried to go back to previous build but it didn't help then I installed updated again and tried to install all new patches via Windows update... with no luck.

I also tried to use software to recover the data but it just gives me a file "soup" as a result.

Is there any better way to fix that?
Where information about partition file system are stored? Is it possible to change that information manually to NTFS and if yes can it help?

Edit:

**[More info about bug.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/partitions-may-be-missing-after-installing-the/ffafb34b-df6e-4c61-927d-babf29b46b87?auth=1&rtAction=1471440530235&lc=1033)**

**[And here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/partition-wont-mount-after-windows-10-anniversary/eff0ea6f-4c2c-4991-817e-4123d933e81e?auth=1)**

Edit 2:

This is what I recently found, do you think that fixing boot record might help?
[image]

Edit 3:
Rebuilding partition boot record didn't helped.

Comment: You can only defer updates for 6 months.  Since the Anniversary feature update was released 6 months ago, your system was recently upgraded to that feature update, you did know that right?  Don't find causation to your partition being lost when your windows installation was updated to the current feature update, because the two events, likely not connected.

Comment: Windows Updates do, indeed, have a reputation for mangling unknown partitions (e.g. Linux). The only thing that can assure restoring these partitions is to make a *full disk image* before the update. Sorry, this won't help your current issue, but after straightening it out as best you can, use imaging software such as Macrium Reflect to back up all partitions.

Comment: @Ramhound As I mentioned I'm using deferred updates which means that I received "Aniversary" 2 days ago, I just thought that my update should be free of that bug because of amount of time which passed.

Comment: If Linux can’t mount it using either the in-kernel NTFS driver or NTFS-3G, the filesystem is corrupted. This obviously can’t be fixed by rolling back the update.

Comment: You should try to use some image tool to get a perfect copy of that disk before you try to fit it. The tool in your screenshot seems to suggest that the backup record is fine (at least the data makes more sense) so restoring it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Questions: (1) Is this 2nd partition or disk? (2) What shows `diskpart` show in `list disk` ? Some tools which are worth trying are: [Paragon](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/rk-free/requirements.html); [Active Partition Recovery](http://www.partition-recovery.com/?gclid=CKaVj5DD2tECFRG6GwodSy4EVw); [AOMEI Partition Assistant Freeware](http://www.disk-partition.com/download-home.html); [MiniTool Partition Recovery](http://www.minitool.com/free-tools/minitool-partitionrecovery.html). Ubuntu also has some [tools](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-corrupted-windows-ntfs-filesystem-ubuntu/).

Comment: @harrymc It is 2nd partition on fist disk. `diskpart list disk` shows 2 hdds. I was trying Minitool, EaseUS and Active@ but they can't recover partiion as partition is still on place but it's file system is broken therefore non of the tools above can read its folders/files

Comment: Manipulations can save or destroy the disk (or fail to do anything), so if you do not have backups and if in addition the above data-recovery tools could not save your data, then be aware that there is a risk. First, I find it weird that MiniTool could not touch this partition : Try to follow this [How to Convert RAW to NTFS tutorial](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/convert-raw-to-ntfs.html).

Comment: Other risky things to try: (1) In Disk Management try to assign the partition a drive letter and if successful use `chkdsk Z: /f` (2) In my [last link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-corrupted-windows-ntfs-filesystem-ubuntu/) follow the section "Fixing A Corrupted Windows NTFS Partition". (3) See this [TestDisk tutorial](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the help. I tried all of above but unfortunately nothing helped. I couldn't force mount the partition under Ubuntu - it showed an error. Partition recovery didn't help as it showed the partition as "current" after scan and there was no recovery option and MiniTool was unable to read files from it. MiniTool data recovery found just about 700 files but there were more than 10000 photos on the partition. chkdsk didn't run on the drive even though it had assigned letter. I'm wondering if people who recover data professionally can do any more?

Comment: Recovery companies excel at physical damages, not this case, but they may have better file recovery products (commercial rather the freebies I recommended). Try first: [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva). Then some trial versions that will be cheaper to pay for if they work than recovery services: [EaseUS](http://www.easeus.com/ad/format-recovery.htm?gclid=CMSZiqrk5tECFQEG0wod9O0A-g),  [diskinternals](https://www.diskinternals.com/ntfs-recovery/) and [Recover My Files](http://www.recovermyfiles.com/). The best is said to be [Ontrack](https://www.krollontrack.com/) ($103) with no trial.

Comment: I recommend using BOOTICE, which I find to be a tool belt. [Here](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bootice.html) is a download link. Select your HDD, click on 'Parts Manage', select your partition and change it's ID to 07 aka the NTFS ID. This should work, assuming all of the other data is untouched.

Comment: @harrymc as the bounty expires soon and you came up with large number of ides, could you please sum that up in the answer because I'd like to reward your effort and such answer can be very helpful for others.

Comment: Done as asked .

Answer (score 4):

The upgrade to Windows 10 may sometimes (rarely) cause a destruction of the
disk. The causes are not known at the moment, and my suggestions in the comments
for saving the poster's data (about 10000 photos) have not yet been all tested.
Nevertheless, the poster has asked me to sum up all my suggestions in one answer
that might be useful for future readers as a compendium of recovery tools and
methods.

Before starting, please note the difference between recovery and repair operations.
The later ones manipulate the destroyed disk and can either save or destroy it
(or fail to do anything). If you do not have backups and if in addition the
data-recovery tools could not save your data, then be aware that there is a risk of losing everything.

Please also note that data should be recovered to another partition/disk, not to the
problematic one. Avoid writing to a partition whose data needs to be recovered.

**Free tools**

1. Start the Command Prompt (cmd), launch `diskpart` and verify that
   the `list disk` command shows the destroyed partition and its displayed type.
   If something is wrong, the partition table needs to be reconstructed.
2. [MiniTool Partition Recovery Free](http://www.minitool.com/free-tools/minitool-partitionrecovery.html) is an excellent tool that can recover
   data but also repair problems.
   For the case of a partition becoming RAW, see the tutorial
   [How to Convert RAW to NTFS](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/convert-raw-to-ntfs.html).
3. [AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition Freeware](http://www.disk-partition.com/download-home.html) can repair
   partitions. Only the paid version ($44.95) can repair the partition type-ID.
4. [Paragon Rescue Kit 14 Free Edition](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/rk-free/requirements.html) can do various repair operations.
5. [Active Partition Recovery is a freeware toolkit](http://www.partition-recovery.com/?gclid=CKaVj5DD2tECFRG6GwodSy4EVw) can do various recovert
   and repair.
6. [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) can recover files.
7. In the Windows Disk Management, try to assign the partition a drive letter
   (Z) and if successful use `chkdsk Z: /f`.
8. Ubuntu has the `ntfsfix` recovery tool for NTFS disks.
   See this article for details :
   [How to Fix a Corrupted Windows NTFS Filesystem With Ubuntu](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-corrupted-windows-ntfs-filesystem-ubuntu/).

**Shareware Tools**

The tools in this section offer a limited version for free that demonstrates
their capabilities. The paid version is required for a full recovery operation.

1. [EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard Professional](http://www.easeus.com/ad/format-recovery.htm?gclid=CMSZiqrk5tECFQEG0wod9O0A-g) ($56) can recover data.
2. [Recover My Files](http://www.recovermyfiles.com/) ($70) can recover files.
3. [DiskInternals NTFS Recovery](https://www.diskinternals.com/ntfs-recovery/) recovers data.

**Commercial tool**

[Ontrack](https://www.krollontrack.com/) ($103) is said to be the best data recovery tool, probably the one
used by professional recovery services.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug - here is a msg from Microsoft on the issue:

> Hello Everyone, I want to give a huge Thank You to all who responded
>   with my diagnostic information requests about their “tanked secondary
>   drives”.  I’m pleased to say that this information enabled us to
>   identify the root cause of the issue.  We are actively building and
>   testing an update to fix this issue into Windows.  We’ll deploy the
>   update via Windows Update as soon as that process is finished,
>   restoring access to your files on the affected drives. In all of the
>   cases that we have diagnosed, files were safely intact on the drives –
>   so please, don’t reformat. You can also access your files by
>   connecting the affected drive to a different machine (not running
>   Anniversary Update), if that is an option for you.   If waiting for an
>   update is not an option, then rolling back will also restore access to
>   your files.  For up to 10 days after installing the Anniversary
>   Update, you have the ability to “go back” or return to the previous
>   build. To uninstall the Anniversary Update: 1.      Open the Settings
>   app. 2.      Select Update & security and then the Recovery tab. 3.
>   Under “Go back to an earlier build”, click the Get started button and
>   follow the instructions. (Note: If more than 10 days have elapsed
>   since installing the Anniversary Update or the “Go back” option is
>   otherwise not available; we ask for your patience until a patch can be
>   released)

And later in the thread -

> I can confirm that the Cumulative Update KB3189866 has fixed the
>   External HDD RAW issue for me.

Full details found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4vyifo/bug_windows_10_anniversary_update_tanked/)

Answer (score 0):

You may try Testdisk tool, which can be extremely effective in such situations, it saved me several times already. It's free and open-source, however you may later decide to donate to the author if you find it useful. :-)

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Download and run the program, then perform analysis of your disk and see if it finds your partition.

Detailed step-by-step instructions are provided here:
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Of course I could quote the whole page of instructions from the Testdisk website, but I think there is little reason to do so as anyway the tool has to be downloaded from the official site and it's better if the original poster would follow the up-to-date instructions on the official site. My intention was mostly to let the original poster know about the tool as a possible solution to their problem.